# Passing img src from flask to html

Tags: python, html, flask, web-applications, jinja2

I am trying to develop a web application for solving the TSP for small instances with different algorithms such as ACO and GA. Its so far working fine but i am somehow not able to correctly pass the image src where the generated graphs are being saved to my html file. The result is that only the alt-tags are being displayed.

Snipped from my route:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
    best_points_ = np.concatenate([best_x, [best_x[0]]])
    best_points_coordinate = points_coordinate[best_points_, :]
    ax[0].plot(best_points_coordinate[:, 0], best_points_coordinate[:, 1], 'o-r')
    pd.DataFrame(aca.y_best_history).cummin().plot(ax=ax[1])
    plt.title("ACO Output & Performance")
    plt.savefig("static/pictures/aco.png"

return render_template("calculator.html", num_points=num_points, max_iter=max_iter, size_pop=size_pop, prob_mut=prob_mut, plot_url="static/pictures/aco.png")
```

My approach on passing the plot_url to my html file:

```
<div class="plot-aco">
            {% if plot_url %}
            <img id="aco-img" src="{{ plot_url }}" alt ="Image cannot be displayed">
            {% endif %}   
        </div>
```

I appreciate any help :) Thanks in advance. I am happy to share more code if needed in order to provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution:

I had to change my html file the following:

{% if plot_url %}

{% endif %}